# SSMS 2008 Merging 2 queries

Tags: sql, variables, merge, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to merge 2 queries that work fine independently and ideally optimise the query in the process.The first query returns various contract information and the last variable '@InYearMonths' determines the total number of months to report in this financial year.

The first query is:

```
Declare @ReportID int, @OrgId nvarchar(10), @FYStartDate DATETIME, @InYearMonths INT
Select @ReportID = '58', @OrgId = '%', @FYStartDate = '2013-04-01', @InYearMonths = '12'

SELECT  Categories.Category, Contracts.ContractName, ContractUptakeStatus.Description AS     UptakeStatus, ContractUptakeStatus.RAGCode AS UptakeRAG, 
        ContractBenefitActuals.ActualValueCR, ContractBenefitActuals.ActualValueCA, ContractSharing.SavingsStartDate, ContractBenefitOpportunity.AnnualSpend, 
        ContractBenefitOpportunity.AnnualisedOppCR, ContractBenefitOpportunity.AnnualisedOppCA, ContractBenefitOpportunity.CurrentFYCR, 
        ContractBenefitOpportunity.CurrentFYCA, ContractBenefitOpportunity.NextFYCR, ContractBenefitOpportunity.NextFYCA, Categories.CategoryColour, 
        ContractSharing.OrgID, Organisations.Organisation, ContractBenefitReporting.Year, ContractBenefitReporting.Period, ContractBenefitReporting.Version, 
        Categories.CategoryForeColour, Contracts.StartDate, Contracts.EndDate, ContractBenefitActuals.ActualSpend,
         CASE WHEN SavingsStartDate IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN 
        DateDiff(MM, SavingsStartDate, CAST('01/04/' + CAST([Year] - 1 AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS datetime)) between -12 and 0 
        THEN(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ActualValueCR),0) as InYearCRSavings
FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContractBenefitActualsDetail.ActualDetailID
ORDER BY ContractBenefitActualsDetail.Period DESC) AS InYearPeriod, *
FROM ContractBenefitActualsDetail
) AS InYearValue
WHERE InYearValue.ActualsID = contractBenefitActuals.actualsid
AND InYearValue.Period <= @InYearMonths) ELSE 0 END ELSE 0 END AS InYearCR,
         ContractUptakeStatus.UptakeStatusID
FROM    ContractBenefitReporting INNER JOIN
        ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport ON ContractBenefitReporting.ReportID = ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport.ReportID INNER JOIN
        ContractSharing ON ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport.ShareID = ContractSharing.ShareID INNER JOIN
        Contracts ON ContractSharing.ContractID = Contracts.ContractID INNER JOIN
        Categories ON Contracts.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID INNER JOIN
        ContractUptakeStatus ON ContractSharing.UptakeStatusID = ContractUptakeStatus.UptakeStatusID INNER JOIN
        Organisations ON ContractSharing.OrgID = Organisations.OrgID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ContractBenefitOpportunity ON ContractSharing.ShareID = ContractBenefitOpportunity.ShareID AND 
        ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport.BenefitVersion = ContractBenefitOpportunity.Version AND 
        ContractBenefitReporting.Year = ContractBenefitOpportunity.FiscalYear AND ContractBenefitReporting.Period = ContractBenefitOpportunity.Period LEFT OUTER     JOIN
        ContractBenefitActuals ON ContractSharing.ShareID = ContractBenefitActuals.ShareID AND 
        ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport.BenefitVersion = ContractBenefitActuals.Version AND 
        ContractBenefitReporting.Year = ContractBenefitActuals.FiscalYear AND ContractBenefitReporting.Period = ContractBenefitActuals.Period
WHERE   (ContractBenefitReporting.ReportID = @ReportID) AND (Organisations.Organisation LIKE @OrgID)
```

The second query is used to determine the variable '@InYearMonths':

```
Declare @FYStartdate datetime, @Reportid int
Select @FYStartdate = '2013-04-01', @Reportid = '58'

SELECT     ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MM, dbo.ContractSharing.SavingsStartDate, @FYStartDate), 0) AS     InYearMonths
FROM         dbo.ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ContractBenefitActuals ON dbo.ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport.BenefitVersion = dbo.ContractBenefitActuals.Version AND 
                      dbo.ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport.ShareID = dbo.ContractBenefitActuals.ShareID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ContractBenefitReporting ON dbo.ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport.ReportID = dbo.ContractBenefitReporting.ReportID AND 
                      dbo.ContractBenefitActuals.FiscalYear = dbo.ContractBenefitReporting.Year AND 
                      dbo.ContractBenefitActuals.Period = dbo.ContractBenefitReporting.Period INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ContractSharing ON dbo.ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport.ShareID = dbo.ContractSharing.ShareID
WHERE     (dbo.ContractBenefitReporting_SharesInReport.ReportID = @Reportid)
```

I need to calculate this '@InYearMonths' variable dynamically within the first query - does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

By dynamically, do you mean that in the first query, the value of @InYearMonths can differ row by row? If not -- if this variable is a singleton, I don't see why you would want to combine the two queries. It seems like the first query depends on the second to evaluate @InYearMonths. Can you clarify the relationship between the two queries a bit more?